# Map location changes when value in spinner changes

Tags: java, android

So I have this activity which lets a user choose a location from a spinner. As the user selects one, the map (fragment under the spinner) will move the camera to a specific destination. I have this code but I can't seem to make it work. Any help will be really appreciated.

**TerminalLocationsActivity.java**

```
public class TerminalLocationsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, OnItemSelectedListener {

Spinner spinner;
GoogleMap mMap, mMap2, mMap3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_terminal_locations);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.terminalList, R.layout.spinner_layout);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Tap box to change terminal.";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL| Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
        toast.show();


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10.699160,122.547208)).title("San Pedro Molo Terminal"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(10.699160, 122.547208), 16));
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String spinSelection = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(spinSelection.equals("Terminal1")) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10.699160, 122.547208)).title("Terminal1"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(10.699160, 122.547208), 16));
    }
    else if (spinSelection.equals("Terminal2")) {
        mMap2.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10.699160,122.547208)).title("Terminal2"));
        mMap2.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(10.699160, 122.547208), 16));
    }
    else if (spinSelection.equals("Terminal3")) {
        mMap3.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10.699160,122.547208)).title("Terminal3"));
        mMap3.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(10.761685, 122.577042), 16));
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
  //do nothing
}
```

}

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it doesn't work?

Comment: Whenever I change the value of the spinner, the map location doesn't update. It's still in the same location when the map is loaded.

Comment: Are you setting the spinner's on item selected listener?